# sencha architect doesnot allow to add plugins for catesianchart

Tags: sencha-architect, extjs6-classic

Am working with sencha archictect4.2.1. We need to use chart and on click of chart series or category it will go to drill down charts.(open a new window and show up charts there).  For chart click event we need to add following plugins:

```
   plugins : {
        ptype : 'chartitemevents',
        moveEvents : true
 }
```

how do I add above plugins into sencha Architect . I dont find any property with this name in cartesian chart component.

Regards,

Comment: Try adding a custom config search plugins and then press the add button.

Comment: http://i67.tinypic.com/m1nqs.jpg